# Download an entire Facebook album for offline browsing?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I would like to download albums off of Facebook onto my iPhone.

I tried the app called "Fb Photos download," but it seems that it downloads only by a group of 12 photos.

Is there an iOS app that downloads all the photos in an album with one click?

Answer (score 1):

One click, batch photo downloads to iOS... try [PhotoSync](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosync-for-facebook/id436669586?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for one of the browser extensions that provide this functionality, because a lot of these downloaders are made for windows or are for older versions of facebook.

Some examples:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fluschipranie/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facepaste/

There are equivalent plugins for chrome as well, just search on the extension sites for facebook album downloader. 
Happy hunting!

Comment: i tagged iPhone :)

Comment: Ah, good point, I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on who owns the album, you may find just using iPhoto does all you need.  If it's your own album, you can set them to sync within iPhoto '09 and '11.  This also makes a handy uploading tool.

Comment: it's my friend album

Comment: iPhoto is not on the iPhone.

Comment: "iPhone" was not in the question I answered before it was edited to make it clearer - check the question history to see what I replied to. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use http://www.picknzip.com/ To Save Picture From Facebook

Answer (score 0):

this message is old but for any that has the same question, you can try this app from appstore fpic2sd. type in the search bar "sandra mouchi" it is for iphone only but can works on an ipad.
ask if you have questions.
thanks